# How to encode tuple as input parameter to function using web3j

Tags: solidity, web3j, abi

I am attempting to call a solidity function that looks something like the following:

```
function fillOrder(
    Order memory order,
    uint256 takerAssetFillAmount,
    bytes memory signature
)
```

Using web3j I would create the function similar to below, however I'm not quite sure how to represent the order which is represented as a struct in Solidity.

```
List<Type> inputParams = Arrays.asList(
    ???, 
    new Uint256(takerAssetFillAmount), 
    new Bytes32(signture)
);

new Function("fillOrder", inputParams, Collections.emptyList());
```

Any pointers on how I should represent the struct? From what I can tell web3j doesn't have support yet for ABIEncoderV2?

Thanks.